# Is there an opposite of setupController?

Tags: ember.js

I am setting `isActive` in setupController:

```
App.EntryRoute = Ember.Route.extend
    setupController: (controller) ->
        controller.set('isActive', true)
```

I would like to remove it when the route is changed.

What is the best way to do this? Are there any hooks for when the controller is removed?

Edit: It seems I asked the wrong thing. I want to trigger this when the model is changed, meaning `deactivate` will not work, as it is only changed when you leave the route.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you need. `setupController` will be called when you change the route and just the model is changing. What is stopping you from using that hook, or that hook plus `deactivate`?

Comment: If I move from `/entries/1` to `/entries/2`, I want to set `isActive` on the entry with `id` of `1` to `false`. `deactivate` is not called because the route is not changing, only the model.

Comment: Interesting. This seems hard, for sure it can be done but really fighting the framework. It is pretty unusual to be modifying model data in response to a change in the route. While you can probably find a way (i will give it some thought) it might be a good time to take a step back and consider if this is really what you want to do. Like would you want to save 'isActive' state of an entry to the api? If you just need to know which model is active in order to update ui it's best to keep in controllers.

Comment: Let's take a step back. I posted the root of the problem    [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508652/how-can-i-render-a-models-template-in-a-list-only-when-on-the-models-route). Thanks for looking into this @MikeGrassotti.

Comment: @jsteiner the question you linked to is much clearer and Teddy Zeeny gave a good solution. I suggest you delete this question to avoid confusing others.

Comment: @jsteiner no problem, that other question is much easier to follow. Agreed w. Luke it makes sense to close this.

Comment: It seems I can't close a question with answers, but I did flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to remove it when the route is changed. What is the best way to do this?

Probably what you are looking for is the route's `deactivate` hook. While not strictly "the opposite" of `setupController`, `deactivate` will be called whenever the router exits the route. Docs here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Deactivate is only called when you leave the route entirely. I also want this to be called when the model is changed.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mike Grassotti already mentioned `deactivate` and his counterpart `activate` are what you might need to solve your problem, this is how you EntryRoute could look like:

```
App.EntryRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  activate: () ->
    @controllerFor('index').set('isActive', true)

  deactivate: () ->
    @controllerFor('index').set('isActive', false)
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To monitor whether the `content` changes, you could create a computed property, that observes the key of the 'content', or something fixed in the model you have loaded. Although I haven't checked this properly, but the code would be something like:

```
modelChanged: function() {
  //do something here
  }.observes('key_in_model')
```

What I don't understand though, is that your code at some point changes the model that is loaded in your controller. Couldn't you use that code to do the transformations/expressions/etc you need done?