# How can I render a model's template in a list, only when on the model's route?

Tags: ember.js

I am iterating a list of `entries` and would like to display the content of each entry within the list, but only when on the respective entry's route.

i.e. - When on route `/entries/2`

```
* link to entry 1
* link to entry 2

  content for entry 2

* link to entry 3
```

Unfortunately, it seems I can't use `{{outlet}}` within the `{{#each entry}}` loop.

Initially I tried to set `isActive` to true within `setupController` on the route, and check for that within the template, but it does not seem like there is a good way to remove that flag when you navigate to `/entries/3` (`deactivate` only works when moving away from `/entries/:entry_id` entirely) . See [Is there an opposite of setupController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16493203/is-there-an-opposite-of-setupcontroller?noredirect=1#comment23691823_16493203) for more on this.

What is the best way to do this with Ember?

Comment: have you tried using the `{{partial}}` helper within the `{{#each}}` instead of the {{outlet}} would this work for you?

Comment: I guess the trick is only rendering the partial when the `entry` is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a an `itemController` with `{{each}}` and set a computed property on that item controller that makes sure the current `model` property is equal to the `App.EntryRoute` current model.

So you would have the following route setup:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('entries', { path: '/'}, function() {
      this.resource('entry', { path: ':entry_id' });
    });
});
```

The following template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="entries">
  {{#each controller itemController="entryItem"}}
    {{#linkTo "entry" this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}} <br />
    {{#if isSelected}}
      {{details}} <br /><br />
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
```

No what you need to do is create the `App.EntryItem` controller and add a computed property `isSelected` which should return true if current route model === `model`

something like this:

```
App.EntryItemController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'entry',

  isSelected: function() {
    return this.get('controllers.entry.model') === this.get('model');
  }.property('controllers.entry.model')
});
```

Here's a fiddle with all of the above applied:

http://jsfiddle.net/teddyzeenny/T2EyK/1/

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the solution in the following way.
Please let me know any short comings in my code.
I am setting a property to Entry model, when calling the entry route to make it visible.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="entries">
    {{#each controller }}
        {{#linkTo "entry" this}}{{name}}{{/linkTo}} <br />
        {{#if visi}}
            <p>{{details}}</p>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('entries', { path: '/'}, function() {
        this.resource('entry', { path: 'entry/:entry_id' });
    });
});

App.Entry = Em.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: null,
    details: null
});

App.entries =[
    App.Entry.create({
        id: 1,
        name: 'entry 1',
        details: 'details 1'
    }),
    App.Entry.create({
        id: 2,
        name: 'entry 2',
        details: 'details 2'
    }),
    App.Entry.create({
        id: 3,
        name: 'entry 3',
        details: 'details 3'
    })
];

App.EntriesRoute=Ember.Route.extend({

    model:function() {
        return App.entries;
    }
});

App.EntryRoute=Ember.Route.extend({

    model:function(params) { 
        var id=parseInt(params.entry_id);
        return App.entries.findProperty('id',id);
    },

    setupController:function(controller,model){
        App.entries.setEach('visi',false);
        model.set('visi',true);
    }
});
```

Regards.